# Set rows of <frameset> dynamically when window size changes

Tags: html, frameset

I don't have much experience of *jQuery*.

I need to set the `rows` attribute of a `<frameset>` dynamically when the browser window is altered.

Here is my frameset: `<FRAMESET BORDER='0' ROWS="112,*" id='reSizeWindow'>`

And the jQuery which I used was:

```
 $('#reSizeWindow').css('rows', $(window).height()+50+'px');
```

This didn't work so I used:

```
<script>
window.onresize = function() {
    var widthViewport = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var el = document.getElementById('reSizeWindow');
    if( widthViewport < 1000 ) {
        el.setAttribute();
        el.rows = '108'
    } else {
        el.rows = '100%';
    }
};
</script>
```

Here I get the error as:

> el is *NULL*

Please help me to get a working *javascript / jQuery*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      var win = $(this); //this = window
      if (win.height() <= 1000) 
       {
          parent.document.getElementsByTagName( 'frameset' )[ 0 ].rows = '108,*'
       }
      else { parent.document.getElementsByTagName( 'frameset' )[ 0 ].rows = '150,*' }
});​​​​
});​​​​
```

Comment: you should have jquery library in your file

Comment: I have `jquery-1.8.0.min.js` .

Comment: is there an issue with `<FRAMESET>` ? I mean, can we alter the `<frameset>` from a `<frame>`. ?

Comment: Still not, but no error this time. Actually, the value is not getting altered. I tried using arbitrary value, it isn't affecting the `rows` at all.

Comment: Worked! changed 100% to a static value like `150`.

Comment: Hmm as expected !! helps means upvote and accept as answer bro

Comment: I have very similar problem. I already tried various combinations but no success.
Hence I tried to debug the behavior by console.log. But it doesn't work 
neither by `window.parent.document.getElementById("bodyFameset").cols().val()`
nether by `parent.document.getElementsByTagName( 'frameset' )[0].cols().val()`

Always getting `getElementsByTagName(...)[0].cols is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked for me with help of [Sridhar R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915384/sridhar-r).

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        var win = $(this);
        if (win.width() <= 1000) { // width() and not height()
            parent.document.getElementsByTagName( 'frameset' )[ 0 ].rows = '150,*';
        } else {
            parent.document.getElementsByTagName( 'frameset' )[ 0 ].rows = '108,*';
        }
    });
});
</script>
```